# Deploying my project in netlify but "build.command" failed to fix

Tags: node.js, datetime, npm, nuget

```
2:47:42 PM: Build ready to start
2:47:44 PM: build-image version: 122b31996ccaffd45d820a452d6227f8312110cc (focal)
2:47:44 PM: build-image tag: v4.5.3
2:47:44 PM: buildbot version: 7eafb394e33f42f945c880ce4ac17c149867813a
2:47:44 PM: Building without cache
2:47:44 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
2:47:45 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
2:47:45 PM: git clone https://github.com/BhautikInfyOm/InfySocial-App
2:47:47 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
2:47:49 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
2:47:50 PM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'frontend/build' versus 'build' in the Netlify UI
2:47:50 PM: Starting build script
2:47:50 PM: Installing dependencies
2:47:50 PM: Python version set to 2.7
2:47:51 PM: Downloading and installing node v16.14.1...
2:47:51 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.14.1/node-v16.14.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
2:47:52 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
2:47:52 PM: Checksums matched!
2:47:57 PM: Now using node v16.14.1 (npm v8.5.0)
2:47:57 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
2:47:57 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
2:47:57 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
2:47:58 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
2:47:58 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
2:47:58 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
2:47:58 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
2:47:58 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.5.0
2:48:00 PM: npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
2:48:00 PM: npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-loader-spinner@6.0.0-0',
2:48:00 PM: npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { npm: 'please-use-yarn', yarn: '>= 1.19.1' },
2:48:00 PM: npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.14.1', npm: '8.5.0' }
2:48:00 PM: npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2:48:11 PM: npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
2:48:19 PM: npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
2:48:32 PM: added 1464 packages, and audited 1465 packages in 33s
2:48:32 PM: 173 packages are looking for funding
2:48:32 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
2:48:32 PM: 6 moderate severity vulnerabilities
2:48:32 PM: To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
2:48:32 PM:   npm audit fix --force
2:48:32 PM: Run `npm audit` for details.
2:48:32 PM: NPM modules installed
2:48:32 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
2:48:32 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
2:48:32 PM: go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
2:48:32 PM: go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
2:48:32 PM: Installing missing commands
2:48:32 PM: Verify run directory
2:48:33 PM: ​
2:48:33 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:48:33 PM:   Netlify Build                                                 
2:48:33 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:48:33 PM: ​
2:48:33 PM: ❯ Version
2:48:33 PM:   @netlify/build 26.4.0
2:48:33 PM: ​
2:48:33 PM: ❯ Flags
2:48:33 PM:   baseRelDir: true
2:48:33 PM:   buildId: 6231ab3673a7c73469d33e7d
2:48:33 PM:   deployId: 6231ab3673a7c73469d33e7f
2:48:33 PM: ​
2:48:33 PM: ❯ Current directory
2:48:33 PM:   /opt/build/repo/frontend
2:48:33 PM: ​
2:48:33 PM: ❯ Config file
2:48:33 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
2:48:33 PM: ​
2:48:33 PM: ❯ Context
2:48:33 PM:   production
2:48:33 PM: ​
2:48:33 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:48:33 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
2:48:33 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:48:33 PM: ​
2:48:33 PM: $ npm run build
2:48:34 PM: > frontend@0.1.0 build
2:48:34 PM: > react-scripts build
2:48:35 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
2:48:37 PM: warn - The `purge`/`content` options have changed in Tailwind CSS v3.0.
2:48:37 PM: warn - Update your configuration file to eliminate this warning.
2:48:37 PM: warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources
2:48:37 PM: warn - The `darkMode` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is set to `false`, which now behaves the same as `media`.
2:48:37 PM: warn - Change `darkMode` to `media` or remove it entirely.
2:48:37 PM: warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#remove-dark-mode-configuration
2:49:06 PM: 
2:49:06 PM: Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.
2:49:06 PM: Most CI servers set it automatically.
2:49:06 PM: 
2:49:06 PM: Failed to compile.
2:49:06 PM: 
2:49:06 PM: src/App.js
2:49:06 PM:   Line 14:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'navigate'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2:49:06 PM: src/components/Pin.jsx
2:49:06 PM:   Line 108:17:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noreferrer" (which implies rel="noopener") is a security risk in older browsers: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/#recommendations  react/jsx-no-target-blank
2:49:06 PM: src/components/PinDetails.jsx
2:49:06 PM:   Line 10:10:  'MdMaximize' is defined but never used                                                                              no-unused-vars
2:49:06 PM:   Line 16:10:  'addingComment' is assigned a value but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
2:49:06 PM:   Line 64:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchPinDetails'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2:49:06 PM: src/components/UserProfile.jsx
2:49:06 PM:   Line 53:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'activeBtn'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2:49:06 PM: src/container/Home.jsx
2:49:06 PM:   Line 33:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'userInfo?.googleId'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
2:49:06 PM: ​
2:49:06 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:49:06 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
2:49:06 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:49:06 PM: ​
2:49:06 PM:   Error message
2:49:06 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
2:49:06 PM: ​
2:49:06 PM:   Error location
2:49:06 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
2:49:06 PM:   npm run build
2:49:06 PM: ​
2:49:06 PM:   Resolved config
2:49:06 PM:   build:
2:49:06 PM:     base: /opt/build/repo/frontend
2:49:06 PM:     command: npm run build
2:49:06 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
2:49:06 PM:     environment:
2:49:06 PM:       - REACT_APP_GOOGLE_TOKEN
2:49:06 PM:       - REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECTID
2:49:06 PM:       - REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN
2:49:06 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/frontend/build
2:49:06 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
2:49:06 PM:   redirects:
2:49:06 PM:     - from: /*
      status: 200
      to: /index.html
Caching artifacts
2:49:06 PM: Started saving node modules
2:49:06 PM: Finished saving node modules
2:49:06 PM: Started saving build plugins
2:49:06 PM: Finished saving build plugins
2:49:06 PM: Started saving pip cache
2:49:06 PM: Finished saving pip cache
2:49:06 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
2:49:06 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
2:49:06 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
2:49:06 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
2:49:06 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
2:49:07 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
2:49:07 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
2:49:07 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
2:49:07 PM: Started saving go dependencies
2:49:07 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
2:49:11 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
2:49:11 PM: Creating deploy upload records
2:49:11 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
2:49:11 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
2:49:11 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m27.044135368s
```

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple warnings/errors in your code that needs to be fixed in order to compile. In the future, please consider compiling a development build on your local machine before pushing your code to a code server like GitHub or Netlify. **Reading the error message will also help.**

Please also [enclose the error message in code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and insert newlines when necessary. This will make it much easier for others to read your error message.

##### TailwindCSS Warning (1)

Change the `purge` property to `content` as you're using TailwindCSS v3.

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  content: [
    // ...
  ],
};
```

[Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources)

##### TailwindCSS Warning (2)

As of TailwindCSS v3, `darkMode` being set to `false` is the same as if it is set to `media`. Remove it entirely as it isn't needed anymore. Only use it when you need it to be set to `class`.

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  dark: false, // remove this
};
```

[Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#remove-dark-mode-configuration)

##### React ESLint Error (3)

It seems like a `useEffect()` in your code is missing a dependency: `navigate`. Depending on how your code works, you will need to either remove the entire dependency array or add the `navigate` dependency to it.

**Removing the entire dependency array:**

```js
// src/App.js
// line 14:6

useEffect(() => {
  // ...
});
```

**Adding the `navigate` dependency:**

```js
// src/App.js
// line 14:6

useEffect(() => {
  // ...
}, [navigate]);
```

This is also the case with:

- `fetchPinDetails` in `src/components/PinDetails.jsx` line 64:6
- `activeBtn` in `src/components/UserProfile.jsx` line 53:6
- `userInfo?.googleId` in `src/container/Home.jsx` line 33:6

##### HTML/React ESLint Warning (4)

In older browsers, if you have a link that opens on a new tab (a.k.a. `target="_blank"`), not including `rel="noreferrer"` is a security risk. Add it to remove the warning. It also implies `noopener` if you're familiar with that, so you don't need to add it.

```
// src/components/Pin.jsx
// line 108:17

<a href="/example-page" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
  // ...
</a>
```

##### ESLint Warning (5-6)

You have variables that are defined but it was never used anywhere. Remove those unless you need to use them.

- `MdMaximize` in `src/components/PinDetails.jsx` line 10:10
- `addingComment` in `src/components/PinDetails.jsx` line 16:10

---

In the future please read error messages before coming to Stack Overflow. *All of these errors or warnings* can be easily resolved if you read them and refer to their linked documentation pages.